# Does the getStaticProps() works in Next JS if I only render static JSX elements with no props or dynamic data?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

In the next js [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props), we can see that getStaticProps function is used to pre-render dynamic code and serve full html code for the client/bots.

And getStaticProps takes in a {params} parameter, returns props which is used by the JSX elements.
But what if I dont have any server side data for a page. All the JSX elements are static. Can I still pre-render those and serve to client as usual?

I have tried without any props, just the getStaticProps function and can't figure it out if it's working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried without any props, just the getStaticProps function and
> can't figure it out if it's working or not.

When you build your next.js project, at the end of the build you'll see a log summary for the build indicating which routes and pages are rendered as SSR or SSG, or ISR usually indicated using a symbol (filled dot or empty dot or a lambda symbol).

getStaticProps is the default behavior if no data-fetching function is used, you probably will see it as (static) on the build log summary.

> All the JSX elements are static
> Can I still pre-render those and serve to client as usual?

When you build your project, next.js will generate (pre-render) HTML for the pages using getStaticProps (or doesn't have any data fetching function) once at build time and will be served on each request, this is also mentioned in their [docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/pre-rendering)

> By default, Next.js pre-renders every page.
> This means that Next.js
> generates HTML for each page in advance, instead of having it all done
> by client-side JavaScript

Comment: Thanks Zakaria, The explanation cleared all my doubts.